# `perl -d` `$DB::single=1` equivalent in `bashdb`

Tags: bash, debugging

I know in Perl debugger `perl -d`, I can put the snippet `$DB::single=1` anywhere in source so the debugger can stop right there.

It is really convenient.

I would like to know is there the equivalent snippet when I use `bashdb` so I can put it in a bash file?

Comment: Tempted to closed due to "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more". What research have you done?

Comment: @glenn jackman, It's not seeking any of those things!?

Comment: That functionality is uncommon, I think. It might not be available. You might have to use breakpoints to achieve the same thing. (I don't know bashdb.)

Comment: Docs: "And if you interrupt the program with a break (a SIGINT signal), you will go into the debugger (assuming your program doesn't trap SIGINT)."  So maybe `kill -INT $$` will do the trick?

Comment: It's asking people to find the docs for that tool and read them for the OP.

Comment: @glenn jackman, Maybe, but that isn't seeking books, tools or software libraries.

Comment: @glennjackman I have read bashdb's docs and I haven't found the things I want. But `$DB::single=1` in Perl is not that easy to find in docs too. Even an experienced Perl programmer may not know it. I knew `$DB::single=1` accidentally and thought it is convenient. So I'm trying to ask someone who have experience both in Perl and bashdb to get help.

Comment: @ikegami Thank you very much. I have tried `kill -INT $$`, it really did the trick. Even though it is not that perfect(the debugger will stop at the first line, but if I `step`, it will go to the right line). I find `kill -INT $$; :` can make it better. `kill -3 $$`, `kill -15 $$` can do the trick too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the question's comment(thanks for every who commented) and the official docs, I find two ways to do this:

1. Add `kill -INT $$; :` in your bash script right before the line you wish to stop, then use `bashdb your-script.sh` to start debug, the debugger can stop but show it was stopped at first line. You can enter `n` and ENTER, then your debugger can stop at the right line.

---

2. Add `source /usr/local/share/bashdb/bashdb-trace` at the beginning of your script(the path may be varied), then add `_Dbg_debugger` right before the line you wish to stop. Use `bash your-script.sh` to start debug, the debugger can stop at your target line correctly. **I recommend to use this method because it is most similar to `$DB::single=1`.**